# Failed to use transforms.ToTensor and transforms.Normalize to normalize the MNIST dataset

Tags: python, pytorch, normalization, tensor, mnist

I used the following code to normalize the MNIST dataset, when I print the first sample, it fails to normalize as the max element is `255`, not `1`.

```
train_transform = transforms.Compose([
   transforms.ToTensor(), 
   transforms.Normalize((0.1307,), (0.3081,))])

train_set = torchvision.datasets.MNIST(
   root=data_dir, train=True, download=True, transform=train_transform)
```

When I check the range of the dataset input images:

```
print("min:%f max:%f" %(train_set.data.min(), train_set.data.max()))
output result:min:0.000000 max:255.000000
```

I was expecting `[0, 1]` instead, I don't know why that is. Is there something wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason why you have a range of `[0,255]` is that you are accessing the underlying data of the dataset via the `data` attribute. This means the transforms have not been applied yet to the data.

```
>>> train_transform = T.Compose([T.ToTensor()])
>>> train_set = torchvision.datasets.MNIST(
       root='.', train=True, download=True, transform=train_transform)
```

Your access of the data:

```
>>> f'min:{train_set.data.min()} max:{train_set.data.max()}'
min:0.000000 max:255.000000
```

You have to access the dataset by its proper interface in order for the transform pipeline to take effect. To make sure you could unroll the entire dataset's inputs into a tensor and look at its range:

```
>>> x, y = zip(*train_set)
>>> x_ = torch.stack(x)
>>> f'min:{x_.min()} max:{x_.max()}'
min:tensor(0.) max:tensor(1.)
```

Comment: Thanks, I see. I have clicked, Please check, if it is correct.